# Can I use an API call to authenticate to a different application with Spring Security?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I am dabbling with Spring Boot. The end goal is to create a simple dashboard that provides statistics & examples on another web application deployed on Tomcat via. API calls. You can also use the API to authenticate via SOAP which is what I would like to do currently (over HTTPS). I've been looking at guides like this one for Spring Security: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-authentication-provider

My main question is: Is Spring Security suitable for what I am trying to do? Based on the link above I have the following code:

```
@Component
public class CustomAuthenticationProvider
  implements AuthenticationProvider {

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) 
      throws AuthenticationException {

        String name = authentication.getName();
        String password = authentication.getCredentials().toString();

        try {

            ApiAuthenticationServiceClient a = new ApiAuthenticationServiceClient();
            a.authenticate(name, password);

            //authentication successful return token
            return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                name, password, new ArrayList<>());

        } catch(ApiAuthenticationException e) {
            //Authentication failed return null
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
        return authentication.equals(
          UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);
    }
}
```

Am I barking up the wrong tree with this? This is more of hobby/learning project so if I am I can always scrap the idea and try something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is certainly one way to approach it. In your example, it is assumed that you have either configured `httpBasic()` authentication

```java
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http...
            .httpBasic();
    }
```

or `formLogin()` authentication

```java
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http...
            .formLogin();
    }
```

Each of these scenarios will insert a filter into the filter chain. Those filters will read the username and password from the header (http-basic) or the HTTP parameters (form-login). It takes those values and creates the UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken and invokes your custom handler.

You can also accomplish this entirely without a custom authentication provider by simply implementing a filter

```java
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http...
            .addFilter(new MyCustomFilter());
    }


    public static class MyCustomFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
        public void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
                                     HttpServletResponse response,
                                     FilterChain chain) {

       if (<should we attempt authentication based on logic> {
           try {
               String username = ...
               String password = ...
               ApiAuthenticationServiceClient a = new ApiAuthenticationServiceClient();
               a.authenticate(name, password);

               //authentication successful return token
              SecurityContextHolder
                  .getContext()
                  .setAuthentication(
                      new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(name, password, new ArrayList<>())
                  );

            } catch(ApiAuthenticationException e) {
                //Authentication failed maybe log it?
            }       
        }
        //continue
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
```

Thousand ways to skin a cat. You pick the one that works for you. The authentication provider approach works, you just have to know that there is a filter that creates the `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken` object for you. If you don't configure those filters, you'll never get the callback to your authentication provider.